# How to pass an array from C# function to VBA?

Tags: c#, arrays, vba

How to pass an array from C# function to VBA?

Can it be done?

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/arraysvbatocssv1.aspx (and also this comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/arraysvbatocssv1.aspx?fid=247508&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=1657817#xx1657817xx ). It's going the other direction, but it may still help.

Comment: I believe this is answered correctly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981404/how-do-i-handle-a-string-array-returned-from-a-c-sharp-method-in-vba?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a COM object in C#, and then reference that COM object like you would any other COM object in VB.

Tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_object_in_c_.aspx

Comment: I think the question is not about creating a COM but about passing an array from c# to VBA once you have a class successfully registered for COM interoperability.

Comment: This was a long time ago.  You're a bit late to the party, aren't you?