# How do I handle a string array returned from a C# Method in VBA

Tags: c#, vba, com, vb6

I have written an assembly in C# which returns a string array, the C# code is below:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class PostcodeFinder
{
    public string[] SearchPostcodes(string postCode)
    {
        var searchService = new QuickAddress("http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/")
                                {Engine = QuickAddress.EngineTypes.Singleline, Flatten = true};

        var mPicklist = searchService.Search("GBR", postCode, PromptSet.Types.OneLine);
        var x = mPicklist.Picklist.Items.Count();

        var resultsToReturn = new string[x];

        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            resultsToReturn[i] = mPicklist.Picklist.Items[i].PartialAddress;
        }

        return resultsToReturn;
    }
}
```

I have then built this assembly, being sure to tick the `Register for COM interop` box in properties. Then in Microsoft Access, I have added the `.tlb` file to the references and created a form with a couple of controls (one of which is a `Listbox` control named `lstResults`). Under the main button control, I have the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    Dim postcodeToSearch As String
    postcodeToSearch = Me.txtPostcode

    Dim c As New PostcodeFinder
    Dim results

    results = c.SearchPostcodes(postcodeToSearch)

End Sub
```

Edit: This runs without error, however when I query the Immediate window with `?results` after putting some dummy code below to allow me to place a breakpoint, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch

Effectively I want to rewrite the following C# code in VBA:

```
var results = c.SearchPostcodes(postcodeToSearch);

foreach(var x in results)
{
    lstResults.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**: Instead of returning `string[]`, try returning `object` instead:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class PostcodeFinder
{
    public object SearchPostcodes(string postCode)
    {
        //Unchanged code

        return (object)resultsToReturn;
    }
}
```

You will still get the type mismatch error in the immediate window when performing `?results` (you need to specify an index such as `?results(0)`), however you are able to iterate through the array as:

```
results = c.SearchPostcodes(postcodeToSearch)
Dim result As Variant
For Each result In results
    MsgBox result
Next result
```

**Original Answer**: You need to instantiate the PostcodeFinder class. In your btnSearch_Click subroutine, try:

```
Dim c As New PostcodeFinder
Dim results

results = c.SearchPostcodes(postcodeToSearch)
```

Alternatively, you could separate the declaration from the instantiation as:

```
Dim c As PostcodeFinder
Dim results
Set c = New PostcodeFinder

results = c.SearchPostcodes(postcodeToSearch)
```

Comment: Ah thankyou. Now this runs without error, however I still don't understand how to deal with the resulting string array. Also, if I put some dummy code below to allow me to place a breakpoint, then use the Immediate window to type `?results` I get `Run-time error '13', Type mismatch`.

Comment: The problem is that you are returning a string array from the SearchPostcodes method, when you need to return a COM object. Here is another SO thread detailing this issue with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948712/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-sharp-function-to-vba.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution to your other question. While I'm unsure if this is the best solution, it provides the expected functionality.

Answer (score 2):

In VBA, the element in a For Each loop must be a Variant when looping thru an array.

```
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In Array("value 1", "value 2", "value 3")
    ' do something with v
Next v
```

Typing `?results` in the Immediate Window is giving an error because VBA can't auto-convert an array into a string. You have to either tell it which part of the array you want, `?results(2)`, or use `Join(sourcearray, delimiter)` to tell it how to convert the array, `?Join(results, ",")`.